# Fixed Table header - how to hide when scrolled off table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the scroll position is greater the beginning of a table, via jquery, I've top-fixed the header row (tr) of a table by "wrap"ing a new table around it (along with prepending some other HTML).  I'm then trying to return it to its original, static position when someone scrolls off the table (either above or below the table), then re-fix the header if the table is scrolled over again.  I'm 80% there, but the having an issue with the ".wrap" and ".prepend" functions that fix the header...they keep firing and that ends up breaking the code.

I played around with ".one" instead of ".on" but it didn't allow the table to re-appear (or hide properly).  Thoughts?

```
var element_menu_hdr = $(".table_start").offset().top;
var element_menu_end = $(".table_end").offset().top;

$(window).on("scroll", function fixmenu() {
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_menu_hdr = element_menu_hdr;
    var scroll_menu_end = element_menu_end;
    if(y_scroll_pos >= scroll_menu_hdr - 10) {


$('.fixable_tr').wrap('<table class="tablepress fixedmenu view"></table>');  
$('.fixedmenu.view').prepend('<tr class="row-1 odd"><th class="column-1"></th><th id="colc" colspan="8" rowspan="1"></th></tr>');


} else if ((y_scroll_pos >= scroll_menu_end - 100) || (y_scroll_pos < scroll_menu_hdr)  ) {

$('.tablepress.fixedmenu.view tbody').contents().unwrap();  
$('.tablepress.fixedmenu.view').contents().unwrap();
$("table.tablepress.fixedmenu.view .row-1.odd").remove(); 

} else {    
    }  // console 
});
```

Comment: Can you check to see if you already have a .fixedmenu.view, and if so, don't do the wrap and prepend again?

Comment: Ahh, good idea. I'm fairly new at Jquery, is there a function that helps w/ a check of that sort?

Comment: Nevermind, just found .length, worked perfectly, thanks for the tip!